# 1.9: programatically switch CMS page template in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, page-layouts

For a bunch of reasons, I'd like to be able to switch a CMS page's template based on some PHP.

In config.xml:

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <Ecomm_Search_set_root_template>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Ecomm_Search/observer</class>
                        <method>setRootTemplate</method>
                    </Ecomm_Search_set_root_template>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

in local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <set_root_template>
        <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/new_template.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </set_root_template>
</layout>
```

In Observer.php:

```
public function setRootTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    //some other logic goes here
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $layout->addHandle('set_root_template');
    return $this;
}
```

Everything is running/working as expected, but the template doesn't switch.  what am I missing here? is there some other thing overriding what I do because it runs last?